# How to stabilize decomposed granite after installation

Tags: landscaping, granite

We had a professional landscaping company install decomposed granite in our front and back yard. They were supposed to use decomposed granite with a stabilizer but instead used a [weed sprayer](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Roundup-1-Gal-EZ-Pump-Sprayer-190500/300259181) to lightly dust the surface with a liquid stabilizer after installation. Needless to say when it rains the decomposed granite is washed away...

My question is as follows:

- Can I stabilize the decomposed granite without having to loosen it all up and re-compacting it?
- How important is it to do the leveling, compacting and stabilizing at the same time? I.e., is it necessary to compact the decomposed granite for the binding/stabilizing agent to work properly?

Comment: Also - not sure if this should be in the [landscaping and gardening forum](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/)